# Unity: How to stop using "Input.GetMouseButton(0)" when pressing on UI Button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player is a magican who can attack enemys with fireballs when pressing the left mouse button.

The code i use is pretty simple (inside the `Update` function):

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot)
{
    canShoot = false;
    Invoke("AllowCanShoot", fireBreak);
    Attack();
}
```

`canShoot` is a `bool` which stops the player from attacking once per frame.

`AllowCanShoot` is a function that sets `canShoot` to `true`.

`Attack()` is the function that handles the attack, not relevant for this question.

I also have a UI Button that appears on screen when the player is near the trader. When the player presses the UI Button he attacks the trader.

What i want is, that he could press the button without attacking him.

I can't disable attacking for the player, because enemys can get to the trader, too, and the player may have to fight then.

What i tried is:

- setting the `canShoot` `bool` to `false`, when the `UI Button` is pressed, but this isn't working, the player is still attacking, maybe the `Update` function gets executed before the `UI Button` function?!

Comment: How about checking to see if the UI button is on the screen? If it is up, disable canShoot.

Comment: Typically games have Enemies tagged with an `Enemy` tag.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you really want to achieve with the UI button? Why don't you just create a function for what you want the button to do?        Or are you just trying to delay the `Attack()` function somehow?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) function to make sure that the mouse is not over a UI object before attacking:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
    canShoot = false;
    Invoke("AllowCanShoot", fireBreak);
    Attack();
}
```

Comment: does this detect Text, too?

Comment: Yes, any UI Object. Also notice the `!` I put in front of it. That's important.

Comment: Sorry to necropost, but is this also mobile-friendly?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't disable attacking for the player, can you make it that when aiming at the trader, the player can't attack him?

Use a Raycast when near the trader.

Something like this maybe?

```
void NearTrader()
{
  if (Vector3.Distance(trader.position, player.position) < myDistance)
  {
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(player.position, PlayerCamera.transform.forward, out hit, myRange))
      canShoot = false;
    else
      canShoot = true;
  }
}
```